# How to capture the backspace event in onChange tag of Form for Reactjs applications

Tags: reactjs

React recommends using the `onChange` event, which does not allow you to use keys like backspace.

```
export const FormDynamicComponent = ({
        formpositions,
        position,
        handleSubmit,
    }: Props) => ( <
        form onSubmit = { handleSubmit } > {
            formpositions.map(
                (formposition, index) => ( <
                    div key = { formposition } >
                    <
                    FormField onChange = { previousPosition(formpositions[formpositions.indexOf(position) + 1], ) }
                    /> </div >
                } < /form> ); / / This code example
                for onChange
```

Comment: You should edit your question and paste the code there rather than in the comments.

Comment: @James Wong i tried to put the code in the question. It didn't allowed me. To format the code i spent 3 hours but still i didn't accepted. Not sure why they are put so many rules to put the code. I edited the code in Visual Studio Code still it didn't accepted. I tried all the rules of stack overflow  but no luck.After all the tries i put the code in comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onKeyDown` instead of using `onChange`. Something like

`<input onKeyDown={(e)=>{if(e.keyCode === 8) console.log("backspace")}}/>`

UPDATE:

[KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) has been deprecated, use [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead: `<input onKeyDown={(e) => { if (e.key === 'Backspace') { console.log('backspace') }}} />`

Comment: [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), but you can easily switch it out with [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead:

`<input onKeyDown={(e) => { if (e.key === 'Backspace') { console.log('backspace') }}} />`

Answer (score 2):

If you are having issues with backspace, attach an `onKeyUp` or `onKeyDown` event but do not remove `onChange`. `onKeyUp` or `onKeyDown` will check after the last character is deleted.

From the code above, you want to include `onKeyUp` like this:

```
<FormField 
onChange = {previousPosition(formpositions[formpositions.indexOf(position) + 1],)}
onKeyUp = {previousPosition(formpositions[formpositions.indexOf(position) + 1],)}/>
```